# How to perform datediff using derived column expression in Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a query in Sql which gives the result of activitystarttime and activityendtime in sec.
Below is the query in sql
DATEDIFF_BIG(second,ActivityStartTime, ActivityEndTime) as [DiffInTime]

I have to write the same using derived column expression.

Comment: So what is stopping you? What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: (ActivityEndTime-ActivityStartTime)/1000L

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT I tried the one u mentioned above, I'm getting NULL's. 
Eg:- If ActivityStartTime is 2022-03-30T07:21:22.2837413Z and ActivityEndTime is 2022-03-30T07:21:28.5825235Z then the differnce between them is 6. But i'm getting NULL's

Comment: @Stu I tried below 2 expressions 
1)minus(second(toTimestamp(ActivityEndTime)),second(toTimestamp(ActivityStartTime))) 
2) minus(seconds(toInteger(ActivityStartTime)), seconds(toInteger(ActivityStartTime)))
I got Nulls for both

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column in `Derived Column's Settings` and write the below expression in `Expression Field` for this column. The new column will have the difference in seconds.

`toInteger(ActiveEndTime-ActiveStartTime)/1000`

[image]

**Note:** Make sure that `ActiveEndTime` and `ActiveStartTime` should be in timestamp format.

Comment: I tried the one u mentioned above, I'm getting NULL's. Eg:- If ActivityStartTime is 2022-03-30T07:21:22.2837413Z and ActivityEndTime is 2022-03-30T07:21:28.5825235Z then the differnce between them is 6. But i'm getting NULL's

Comment: is your data is in timestamp format?

Comment: My data is in the format ActivityStartTime = 2022-03-30T07:21:22.2837413Z and ActivityEndTime = 2022-03-30T07:21:28.5825235Z
 I also tried in below 2 ways 1)minus(second(toTimestamp(ActivityEndTime)),second(toTimestamp(ActivityStartTime))) 
2) minus(seconds(toInteger(ActivityStartTime)), seconds(toInteger(ActivityStartTime)))